electron forge - DevTools hidden by default on launch
I wan to set devtools hidden by default in a electron forge app. I don't want to disable it just to hide them in start up
electron app devTools showed by default
If I turn devTools to false it's gets disabled and can't be opened with ctrl+shift+I
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
width: 800,
height: 600,
webPreferences: {
preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
devTools: false,
},
autoHideMenuBar: true
});
I need to bi hidden not disabled

can you include your code, the dev tools window is not supposed to be shown on default.
